# How to POST to Jenkins to build a job with basic auth headers?

Tags: jenkins, curl, opsgenie

I'm trying to configure a well-known incident management tool to perform a POST request to a Jenkins job build URL to respond to some alerts.

In this tool, for some reason **I cannot put** the Jenkins job build endpoint as follows:

```
https://<user>:<apiToken>@my-jenkins.com/blabla/job/blabla/build?token=<myTokenName>
```

So, the only alternative the tool provides is putting the authorization details **as a header**.

Before doing that, I'm trying to check if that would work, **using `curl`**. For that reason, I'm calling that Jenkins URL with the Basic auth header, with the following `curl` command:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization:Basic <user:apiToken in base64>' -H 'Jenkins-Crumb:<my-crumb>' 'https://my-jenkins.com/blabla/job/blabla/build?token=<myTokenName>'
```

But is giving me a **401: Not authorized (Invalid password/token for user: my-user)**. If I place the same credentials in the URL as the first code snippet it works.

I have read the following docs: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients and it seems setting the Basic auth header is pretty straight forward, but I think I'm missing something here because it doesn't work for me when I use `curl`.

Also I Googled a little bit and it seems everyone calls the Jenkins job build URL with the `user:apiToken` in the URL, but as I mentioned, the tool doesn't allow to put URLs like that.

**Has anyone performed a Jenkins job launch with a basic auth header?**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Okay... Quite embarrasing but it seems that I was generating the base64 string with my macOS command line shell, but it wasn't working.

I did the same with Postman to generate the auth header and now it's working...

Hope that helps someone, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same issue. Below is my solution.

1. Using a Nginx proxy behind IAP & in front of Jenkins
2. Using new header for Jenkins instead of "Authorization". For me I used "Jenkins-Authorization" header.
3. In Nginx configuration I used "proxy_set_header" to set "Authorization" header from "Jenkins-Authorization".
4. In Nginx configuration, proxy_pass to upstream Jenkins server by using internal IP

Nginx configuration:

```html
upstream app {
    server jenkin_internal_ip:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_jenkins_authorization;
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

- remember replace "jenkin_internal_ip" in Nginx configuration as your Jenkins internal IP.